# Sharing Mapped network drives from host with VM on VMWare Workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation

Can I access my network drives on my host machine on the VM?

This is possible on Virtual PC but I can't find the setting on VMware.

I am running Windows 7, VMWare workstation 7.1.3 build-324285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you mean?

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html